# How to test the className of an Input Field in React testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am new to React and React testing and I'd really appreciate some help with the testing part.

I'm going to put all the code here for understanding, therefore sorry that it is so long.

I have some input fields that require a user to fill them out. As soon as they are clicked once, but not filled with text the border of them gets red (validateInput()). I do that by setting the className to "error". When a field is filled, the className changes to null (because of change in the state) and therefore the css stops applying on that field. This is my code for the field named "title".

**TripForm.jsx:**

```
class TripForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        title: "",
        //more states ...
      },
      tripErrors: {
        titleError: "",
        //more states ...
      },
    };
  }

validateInput = () => {
    let nam = window.event.target.name;
    let val = window.event.target.value;
    const data = { ...this.state.data, [nam]: val };
    this.setState(() => ({ data }));
    let tripErrors = this.state.tripErrors;
    switch (nam) {
      case "title":
        tripErrors.titleError = val.length > 0 ? "" : "required";
        break;
      //more cases...
    }
  };

 render() {
    const { tripErrors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <h1 style={headerStyles}> Create an individual trip </h1> <br />
          <Form>
            <FormGroup as={Row}>
              <Form.Label column sm={1}>
                Title
              </Form.Label>
              <Col sm={5}>
                <Form.Control
                  className={tripErrors.titleError.length > 0 ? "error" : null}
                  name="title"
                  aria-label="title"
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.props.handleChange(e);
                    this.validateInput();
                  }}
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            //more input fields here...
            </FormGroup>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TripForm;
```

**App.css:**

```
input.error {
  border: 2px solid #c45c5c;
}
```

I want to write a test that checks that the className is actually set to "error" or contains nothing if a user filled somthing out.

**TripForm.test.js without user input:**

```
test('check if title field is required',  () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const utils = render(<BrowserRouter>
      <TripForm />
    </BrowserRouter>, div);
    const input = utils.getByLabelText('title')
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: '' } })
    //here comes the error:
    expect(input).toHaveClass("error");
});
```

this is the error:

```
expect(element).toHaveClass("error")
    Expected the element to have class:
      error
    Received:
      form-control
```

When I write the test differently, so that it checks that className is empty because the user gave it a value I get a huge error message:

**TripForm.test.js with user input:**

```
test('check if title field is required',  () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const utils = render(<BrowserRouter>
      <TripForm />
    </BrowserRouter>, div);
    const input = utils.getByLabelText('title')
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'trip1' } })
    expect(input).toHaveClass(null);
});
```

this is the error for that:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Caught error after test environment was torn down

Cannot read property 'body' of null
(node:83) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag ...

for the TripForm.jsx:
TypeError: this.props.handleChange is not a function

      60 |                   type="text"
      61 |                   onChange={(e) => {
    > 62 |                     this.props.handleChange(e);
         |                                ^
      63 |                     this.validateInput();
      64 |                   }}
      65 |                 />


for the TripForm.test.js:
 expect(element).toHaveClass(expected)
    At least one expected class must be provided.

    > 26 |     expect(input).toHaveClass(null);

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/TripForm.test.js:26:19)
```

Has anyone an idea how i can solve this and just check if after an Input the className is null and without one it is "error"? Do I need to change something in TripForm.jsx?

Thank you a lot for reading.